# How do I use the launchmyapp plugin with phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use the launchmyapp plugin to open another app within my app.  I want to open mydeals:// but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I added this to my config.xml.

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp">
```

`<param name="URL_SCHEME" value="mydeals" />`
`</gap:plugin>`

Then I am using this:  `var my_window = window.open('mydeals://', '_system');` to open the app.  I am not sure if the param name or value is wrong.

Comment: Are you using phonegap build or the CLI?

Comment: I am using phonegap build

Answer (score 0):

This is custom applaunch plugin. it works when app is installed it directlly launch if not than open PlayStore

Your `index.js`  on button click to launch app code

AppChecker is service.
appcheker is action.
`com.outfit7.mytalkingtomfree` is package name which app you want to launch.

```
    $(".appopenclass").on("click",function () {

        cordova.exec(function(winParam) {},
           function(error) {
              utils.setAlertMsg("Plugin failed " + error);
           },
           "AppChecker",
           "appchecker",
           ["com.outfit7.mytalkingtomfree"]);

    });
```

project->res->xml->config.xml

```
<feature name="AppChecker">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.appview.openapp.AppChecker" />
</feature>
```

Create one package like name `com.appview.openapp` and create new class name like `AppChecker.java`

AppChecker.Java

```
    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class AppChecker extends CordovaPlugin {

        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
                CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            if (action.equals("appchecker")) {
                String message = args.getString(0);

                this.appchecker(message, callbackContext);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void appchecker(final String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
            if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
                // callbackContext.success(message);

                Log.i("test", "" + message);

                // appInstalledOrNot(message);

                cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot(message);
                        if (installed) {
                            // This intent will help you to launch if the package is already
                            // installed
                            Intent LaunchIntent = cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager()
                                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(message);
                            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(LaunchIntent);

                            System.out.println("App already installed on your phone");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("App is not installed on your phone");

                            try {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + message));
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

                            }


                        }

                    }
                });



            } else {
                callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
            }
        }

        private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
            PackageManager pm = cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
            boolean app_installed = false;
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                app_installed = true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                app_installed = false;
            }
            return app_installed;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am using phonegap build so I don't have access to java files

Comment: In your system have u intalled android, means u have Android sdk if yes than try to manaly create and edit all file what i have mention in this aswe

Comment: Is there any way to do this in just javascript without java code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use the wrong plugin here.

As I understand it, lanchmyapp helps you register your app so it can be called by an other app by invoking a url.

What you seem to be trying to achieve is launch an other app from your app. For that you should have a look at the [WebIntent plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/43).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Now to use the webintent plugin for my purpose, would I need to use startActivity method?  How would I go about using it?  The app package I need to open is called com.access.access